# Creating a Circle when the mouse clicks the Screen

Tags: javascript

I want to draw a circle with 5 pixels radius on the screen every time the mouse clicks the screen. However, if the mouse is being held down (with left click) I want a circle to be created every 20 milliseconds.

With this method, I am attempting to create a simple paint tool for a coding exercise/fun, but have no clue how to do so. Although I would prefer a direct answer, it would also help if someone could point me in the right direction (what should I take a closer look at?).

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to StackOverflow! Generally, people here love to help but it's usually expected that you show some attempt to solve the problem yourself, and describe where you got stuck when you hit a specific problem. Your question is probably too broad and open-ended, and might get closed. I would start by Googling for things like "JavaScript click event". Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: Sorry about the broad question. I googled it, and had no luck. I just had no clue what element to look at. Thanks for the input though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get closer look at canvas element.
http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp
and so on...

Example of canvas application:

[image: Example of canvas]